# How to monitor mosquitto server through HTTP

Tags: mosquitto

How to monitor mosquitto server through HTTP? I am looking something like https://my.mosquitto.server.com/health or https://my.mosquitto.server.com/info.

- Mosquitto Server: v3
- OS: CentOS 7
- Mosquitto Web: Enabled

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please update your findings.

Comment: @Mebin Joe, I have tried using the $SYS topic and was able to get the metrics of the server. I am looking for an approch to directly find the health information of the server through HTTP rather that using an another mosquitto client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always going to need a MQTT client to get access to the information in the `$SYS` topic space.

When MQTT over Websockets is enabled you can have mosquitto serve a page that will connect to the broker with the Paho Javascript client with MQTT over Websockets. The page can subscribe to what ever topics you want.

e.g. You can use the `http_dir` option to specify a directory that moquitto will server static files from. Here you could deploy a slightly modified (The modification would be to change the topic from `#` to `%SYS/#`) version of my [D3 MQTT topic tree viewer](https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2013/03/24/d3-mqtt-tree-visualiser-updated/) (code on [github](https://github.com/hardillb/d3-MQTT-Topic-Tree)).

From the [mosquitto.conf](https://github.com/hardillb/d3-MQTT-Topic-Tree) man page:

> **http_dir** *directory*
>
> When a listener is using the websockets protocol, it is possible to
>   serve http data as well. Set http_dir to a directory which contains
>   the files you wish to serve. If this option is not specified, then no
>   normal http connections will be possible.
>
> Not reloaded on reload signal.